# Hostlistener wait

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is there anyway to listen to custom events in angular 2 in intervals ? like once in  3 seconds ?

```
export class scrollDirectiveComponent {
    pageNo: any = 1;
    @Input() pageNumber: any;
    @Output() emitPageNumber: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event) {
        console.log('scrolled', event.target.scrollTop);
        let tracker = event.target;
        let limit = tracker.scrollHeight - tracker.clientHeight - 5;
        console.log(event.target.scrollTop, limit);
        if (event.target.scrollTop > limit) {
            this.pageNumber++;
            this.emitPageNumber.emit(this.pageNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps on listening to scroll event and the page number is automatically incremented . If one cannot wait then is there anyway in which the scroll bar can be changed to a new position?

Comment: You want to emit event once in 3 second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as i understood then you can do like this, on each scroll event you emit to observable and on observable throttleTime(3000) it means that only one event will go through.

```
export class scrollDirectiveComponent {
  pageNumber: any = 1;
  private scrollEvents = new Subject();
  constructor() {
    scrollEvents
      .throttleTime(3000)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.emitPageNumber.emit(++this.pageNumber);
      });
  }

  @Input() pageNumber: any;
  @Output() emitPageNumber: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    console.log('scrolled', event.target.scrollTop);
    let tracker = event.target;
    let limit = tracker.scrollHeight - tracker.clientHeight - 5;
    console.log(event.target.scrollTop, limit);
    if (event.target.scrollTop > limit) {
      this.scrollEvents.next(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Other option to look would be something like this, but i am not sure you need to try since i have never done directive

```
constructor(private _el: ElementRef){
  Observable.fromEvent(_el, 'resize')
    .throttleTime(3000)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.emitPageNumber.emit(++this.pageNumber);
    });
}
```